# Why is this code working only in one case?

Tags: python, primes

I am new to python and I am trying to make a prime numbers generator in a range, I found this code online:

```
from math import sqrt
import time
t1 = time.time()
primenumbers=[2,3,5]

for i in range(7,1000,2):
    sq = sqrt(i)+1
    for j in primenumbers:
        if sq < j:
            primenumbers.append(i)
            #print i, len(primenumbers)
            break

        if i % j == 0:
            break

print primenumbers
t2 = time.time()
print (t2 - t1)
```

but if I change

```
for i in range(7,1000,2):
```

with

```
for i in range(10,1000,2):
```

in output I only get numbers 2 3 and 5, and if I make the primenumbers array empty instead of it containing 2 3 and 5, in output I get an empty array, it won't be filled with prime numbers. If you can just tell me what is wrong, I can't figure it out

Comment: Why would you change the 7 to a 10? Is there a reason you would expect that to be useful, or are you just fiddling with the code and seeing what happens?

Comment: 10 is even, range(10, somenumber, 2) will give you even numbers, obviously not primes.

Comment: i need a program for finding prime numbers in a range, for example from 100 to 1000

Comment: Do you need it for homework? Because if you do, you probably shouldn't plagiarize code off the internet.

Comment: No in school I am learning pascal and I am now at for function in pascal lol, I am learning python on my own, and I use internet codes to study them through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the `range` function to get this behavior (and the essence of the program you used too).

`range(7,1000,2)` gives you a list of integers starting from `7` which are less than `1000` and are computed by adding `2` to previous number - so the series of numbers that you get are `9`,`11`,`13`,`15`.. and so on.

`range(10,1000,2)` gives you a list of integers starting from `10` and which all will be divisible by `2` hence no primes in the list.

-- This program can help you --

```
primes = []
for i in range(1,100,2): # <==== change here - make sure first argument is odd
  prime = True
  for j in range(2,i-1):
    if i % j == 0:
      prime = False
      break
  if prime:
    primes.append(i)
print primes
```

Comment: so how can I change it so I get primes in a range from 100 to 1000 for example?

Comment: use `range(100,1000,1)` i.e. all test on all numbers.

Comment: https://ideone.com/mqqj8E here is my code here, I get only 2 3 and 5 again if I put 100,1000,1 , and if I put empty array I get an empty array also

Comment: I am sorry for suggesting that - since I assumed something else for the logic under. Let me check it.

Comment: @Luka please check the above program which finds primes between `1` and `100` so if you want primes between `100` and `1000` replace `1` with `101` (first odd number after `100`) and `100` with `1000` and execute.